# Swift: Cannot access methods from declared library

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, html-to-pdf

**On a side-note: I would like to apologize if the title is misleading. Couldn't find a better title for this question.**

I imported the [**NDHTMLtoPDF**](https://github.com/MyAppConverter/HTMLtoPDF-Demo-Swift) library to my Xcode application.

In the demo of the library, this is how they use the library:

```
class NDViewController :UIViewController, NDHTMLtoPDFDelegate
{
    var PDFCreator:NDHTMLtoPDF?
[...]
    @IBAction func generatePDFUsingDelegate( sender:AnyObject ){
        self.resultLabel?.text = "loading..."
        let tt:NSString = ("~/Documents/delegateDemo.pdf" as NSString).stringByExpandingTildeInPath
        self.PDFCreator = NDHTMLtoPDF.createPDFWithURL(NSURL(string:"http://edition.cnn.com/2012/11/12/business/china-consumer-economy/index.html?hpt=hp_c1")!, pathForPDF:tt, delegate: self, pageSize: CGSizeMake(595.2,841.8), margins:UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 5, 10, 5)) as? NDHTMLtoPDF;
    }
}
```

In my application, I do the same thing: I declare the `PDFCreator` variable as an `NDHTMLtoPDF?` type, I added `NDHTMLtoPDFDelegate` at the class declaration where I use the library instance, and I wrote the following code in my method:

```
let tt:NSString = ("~/Documents/delegateDemo.pdf" as NSString).stringByExpandingTildeInPath
self.PDFCreator = NDHTMLtoPDF!.createPDFWithHTML("Hello", pathForPDF: tt, pageSize: CGSizeMake(595.2,841.8), margins:UIEdgeInsetsMake(36, 36, 36, 36))
```

Every time I type `self.PDFCreator = NDHTMLtoPDF!.`, I only get autocompletes for the following methods:

`createPDFWithHTML(self:NDHTMLToPDF)`
`createPDFWithURL(self:NDHTMLToPDF)`

If I type `self.PDFCreator = NDHTMLtoPDF.`, Xcode complains that this is an `ambiguous reference to member <insert_member_here>`.

However, if I do `self.PDFCreator.`, I suddenly get `createPDFWithURL( URL:NSURL ,pathForPDF PDFpath:NSString ,delegate:AnyObject ,pageSize:CGSize ,margins pageMargins:UIEdgeInsets )` as an autocomplete option. I attempted to run my code with that only, but it turns out the method is never called (I checked by adding `print` calls in the methods).

I am seriously at a loss.

Thank you for any help you may provide!

If you need any extra code, let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after fiddling with it some more, I figured it out. The solution is simple: update the code to the latest `Swift 2.0` syntax.

I took the liberty of forking the repository and fixing it myself. I made a pull request, but if you want to get a copy of it before they merge it into the official master branch, go grab it [here](https://github.com/chrissar/HTMLtoPDF-Demo-Swift).